# Splitting a row into 2 rows based on data in a single column

Tags: r

This question already has answers here:
Split comma-separated strings in a column into separate rows (6 answers)
Split delimited strings in a column and insert as new rows [duplicate] (6 answers)
Your post has been associated with similar questions. If these questions don’t answer your issue, edit your question to highlight the difference between the associated questions and yours. If edited, your question will be reviewed and might be reopened.

Find out more about duplicates and why your question has been closed.

Closed 4 mins ago.

I have a single row and I wish to split it onto 2 rows based on the value in one of the columns. So I want to split the value in the gender column using the + symbol and create 2 rows based on mens and womens here, (mens and womens will sometimes slightly change to man+woman so I want to stay consistent using the +. A better example of what I'm looking to do is below.

```
mydf
gender             country   date        field  latitude longitude
Mens1+Womens1      UK        20240226    both  NA        NA

mynewdf
gender       country   date        field  latitude longitude
Mens1        UK        20240226    both  NA        NA
Womens1      UK        20240226    both  NA        NA
```

I have tried using a couple of different ways with no real lush, these are;

```
stack(setNames(strsplit(mydf$name,'+'),), )
```

and

```
mydf[rep(nrow(mydf), each = 2), ]
```

I think I'm missing the last argument for the stack attempt but the rep attempt works however it just simply repeats the row so I have 2 of the same

Comment: `library(tidyverse);mydf %>% separate_rows(gender, sep = "\\+")`.. remember that the `+` is a special regex character, so it needs to be escaped.